# justify-content-md-center not working?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm following a tutorial and I want to use justify-content-md-center when it reaches medium screen size. But it doesnt seem to work.

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="background:lightblue">
      <div class="col-md-2">col-sm-6</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">col-sm-6</div>
      <div class="col-md-2">col-sm-6</div>
    </div>
      <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-2">col-sm-2</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">col-sm-2</div>
        <div class="col-md-2">col-sm-2</div>
      </div>

  </div>
```

I appreciate the help thanks

Comment: What bootstrap version are you using? This is only available in v4.

Comment: im using V4, but i cant get justify content working on certain viewports. Only "row justify-content-center" works

Comment: Is that supposed to work in a row/col situation? The examples under https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/#justify-content all seem to be using different classes altogether.

Comment: Have you read this: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/. There are useful examples there.

Answer (score 2):

**Hope this works**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   

<div class="row justify-content-center" style="background: darkgray;">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" alt="sample image">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" alt="sample image">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Hope this works" is not a valuable comment, please add some descriptive comment

Comment: Does not work at all